# SharePoint Online: Find SPOSiteDesign GUID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

To all you SharePoint masters.

I'm testrunning a .ps1 to provision a custom made teamsite-template (.json file)
After testing (a lot) the script is working.

However now I have a dropdownlist of many dummy-templates.

Anyt hero who know how to delete these template trough Powershell?
I can't seem to look up the specific GUID for the cmdlet Remove-SPOSiteDesign.

FYI - added is the code I used to provide the site template.

```
$site_script = 
@'
 {
    "$schema": "schema.json"    ,
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Site scripting test list 0",
            "templateType": 100,
            "subactions": [
                {
                    "verb": "setTitle",
                    "title": "SiteScriptingTestListTitle2"
                },
                {
                    "verb": "setDescription",
                    "description": "Site scripting test list description 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bindata": { },
    "version": 1
 }
'@



$SiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript  -Title "Create customer tracking list"  -Content $site_script  -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information"
Add-SPOSiteDesign  -Title "Contoso customer tracking"  -WebTemplate "64"  -SiteScripts $SiteScript.Id  -Description "Tracks key customer data in a list"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all Site Designs use:

```
Get-SPOSiteDesign | select Id, Title, Description
```

To remove Site Design use:

```
Remove-SPOSiteDesign -Identity "site-design-id"
```

Do not forget to clean also Site Scripts used in deleted Site Designs.

```
Get-SPOSiteScript | select Id, Title, Description
Remove-SPOSiteScript -Identity "site-script-id"
```

If you want to remove all Site Designs and Site Scripts in one go you can use PowerShell pipes:

```
Get-SPOSiteDesign | Remove-SPOSiteDesign
Get-SPOSiteScript | Remove-SPOSiteScript
```

> Reference:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-powershell

Comment: Hi Lukas. This one did the trick.
I put them in a $var and could easily foreach-loop them and delete.

Comment: @Emiel see updated answer for removing all designs and scripts in one go.